# Why does the M61 Vulcan have a flash suppressor?

Tags: united-states, aircraft

In most pictures of an [M61 Vulcan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M61_Vulcan), you can see a [flash suppressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_suppressor) (clearly not a muzzle brake, which could've made some sense to me).

[image: Wikipedia reference image of M61 Vulcan copyright free to use as referenced on that page]

Knowing that these were mostly used on US military fixed-wing aircraft, why was the flash suppressors added? On rifles, the goal is usually to prevent the operator from being blinded in low-light environments, which I doubt would be a problem for an aircraft pilot, unless I'm mistaken?

An alternate explanation would be that it's meant to make the aircraft harder to spot when firing, but I doubt that the flash suppressor would work well enough, if visual spotting during firing even is that big of a factor to take into account.

Comment: Can you provide a reference image? The ones [I found](https://www.google.com/search?q=M61+Vulcan&newwindow=1&tbm=isch) lack anything that I'd identify as a flash suppressor.

Comment: The M61 seems to have a range of muzzle arrangements, possibly dependent on how and where it is mounted and used. There may be applications where a flash suppressor makes sense.

Comment: A pilot can be blinded by muzzle flash, no problem, particularly at night.  Imagine a big spotlight being turned on while it is firing.  Particularly on the F-15, -16 and -18, the muzzle is close to the pilot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: A barrel muzzle clamp for the M61A1 Vulcan]

Source: [International Military Antiques website](https://www.ima-usa.com/products/original-u-s-m61a1-20mm-vulcan-rotary-cannon-barrel-muzzle-clamp-as-used-on-f4-phantom?variant=30987403100229)

This image shows a barrel muzzle clamp for the M61A1 Vulcan which was in an externally mounted gun pod used on a F-4 Phantom II fighter jet (since the early F-4s didn't have an internally mounted gun). In addition to acting as a barrel clamp, this particular design also serves as both a flash hider and a muzzle brake. These gun pods could be mounted under the wings or on the underside of the fuselage (or both). When you're mounting them under the wing, there's a chance that they'll be visible from the cockpit when firing so flash might be an issue.

An image of the pod can be found on Flikr: [F4 Phantom Vietnam War fighter jet undercarriage gatling gun pod - Mr Freek](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mrfreek/2300614041)

The later F-4E Phantom models had a nose mounted M61 which featured a simpler type of barrel clamp without the flash hider.

Comment: This answer doesn’t explicitly answer the "why" of the question.